# Get Posts updated or published within the last x hours

Tags: filters, query-posts, posts-where

Okay, I'm trying to get posts that have been published within the last x amount of time, options being 8, 24 or 72 hours. I have the variables being passed to my featureHandler.php via ajax, then returning the posts, here is how I'm doing it:

```
$vars = $_GET['vars'];
$time = $vars[0];
$order = $vars[1];

if ($time == 8 ) {
    function filter_where($where = '') {

        //posts in the last 8 Hours
        $where .= " AND post_date > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hours'))."'";
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where', 10, $time);
} elseif ($time == 24) {
    function filter_where($where = '') {

        //posts in the last 24 Hours
        $where .= " AND post_date > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours'))."'";
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where', 10, $time);
} elseif ($time == 72) {
    function filter_where($where = '') {

        //posts in the last 72 Hours
        $where .= " AND post_date > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-72 hours'))."'";
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where', 10, $time);
}

?>

<div class="article-wrapper">
<?php

query_posts(array(
       'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
));

$itemCount = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

This is semi working, I think, except that a post I just created, only shows up in 24 or 72, but not in the case that $time==8, why is that? And how can I make this code more efficient?

Thank you SINCERELY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a shorter version that assumes the GET parameter **?time=[integer]** (for example ?time=8)

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where', 11);
function filter_where($where = '') {
    if(isset($_GET['time'])){
        $time = $_GET['time'];
        $time=(int)$time; // only allow integers
        if(in_array($time,array(8,24,72))){
            $where .= " AND post_date > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-".$time." hours'))."'";
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the filter after the query?

Comment: Rather, do I need to remove the filter, prior to updating the filter and running the query again?

Comment: usually I put my filters in the file functions.php

Comment: any luck so far?

Comment: Well the variable in the $where . = etc, was not reading correctly, so instead i used a variable to $fromTime = '-' . $time . 'hours; and put $fromTime directly into strtotime. 

This worked, and i found out the reason why the correct posts were not displaying was because the date function returns UTC, and the post times are saved in local time.